# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type) in Java RESTful web service call

Tags: java, jquery, json, rest

I have the following javascript in my test html page to send ajax requests to a java restful web service I built with netbeans (mostly auto generated by using 'Restful web services from database' function).
Here is the ajax query from my test html page:

```
$(function(){
$('.message-button').on('click', function(e){

    var resultDiv = $("#resultDivContainer");

      $.ajax({
                    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                    },
                    'type': 'POST',
                    'url':  'http://localhost:8080/xxxAPI/api/activity',
                    'data': { "baseItemId": "2" },
                    'dataType':'json',
                    'success': function(data) {
                        var xmlstr = data.xml ? data.xml : (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(data);
                        $("#resultDivContainer").text(xmlstr);
                    },
                    'error': function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(' Error in processing! '+textStatus + 'error: ' + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
})
});
```

Also here is the part of my java code that accepts post requests:

```
@POST
    @Override
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void create(XxxxxActivity entity) {
        super.create(entity);
       }
```

When I request from the test page (for this version of the test page), I get this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415
>   (Unsupported Media Type)

or this error:

> POST http://localhost:8080/xxxAPI/api/activity 415 (Unsupported
>   Media Type)

So far I have tried making various changes to the ajax request as advised on similar questions on stackoverflow, including changing type to `jsonp`, putting json data in double quotes, adding headers and changing data type to xml. None of them have worked.

Also since I manage to get a response from the server at times, I wonder if the issue is with xml parsing in the java code. I believe a potential fix would be to add the jackson jar files, but I have no idea how to add them on netbeans as there is no lib folder in WEB_INF.

I would also like to know if there is any issue with the jquery ajax request. This issue has been bugging me for days.

**PS**: Also note that GET requests from the browser work fine. I have not used maven in this project.

Comment: Did you add the JSON libraries to your web application (either moxy, Jackson , genson etc)?

Comment: @dsp_user no, I'm trying to figure out where to add jackson. In the libraries folder there are two subfolders called Apache tomcat and jdk 1.8. Which one is the right folder? or is it WEB INF/lib as in eclipse?

Comment: Yes, WEB-INF/lib. However, I never managed to get Jackson to work (I didn't use Maven so I had some versioning issues). I'm using MOXY (jersey-media-moxy-2.23.jar). I also had to add some additonal jars but don't remember which. The easiest way to add Jackson is probably using Maven but I can't help you with that.

Comment: @toing_toing WEB-INF/lib is the right folder but error 415 is not related to libraries.

Comment: 415 is saying that the object you are passing in data : { } and the object you are receiving on server side XxxxxActivity entity doesn't match. You should write your data such a way that it will exactly match with the property of your entity object.

Comment: It was in my case. When I added all the necessary libraries, it disappeared.

Comment: Make sure that you have the correct Jackson version. (depending on the Jersey version)

Comment: BTW, if you think that your libraries are installed/deployed correctly, you can try to call that method from a console application. This could potentially indicate that the problem is indeed in the ajax call.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
'data': { "baseItemId": "2" },
```

with

```
'data': JSON.stringify({ "baseItemId": "2" }),
```

Object JSON is available [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

**EDIT**

- add attribute `contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'`
- remove attribute headers from ajax call.

Comment: `remove attribute headers`.., this is not clear to me

Comment: @toing_toing remove headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                    },

Comment: got it, thank you. do we need quotes for that too? like `'contentType': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'`

Comment: For me, It has worked as i keep the 'Accept' header and adding charset to 'Content-Type' header  as you mention. Just 'Content-Type' header, it keeps giving error.

Comment: The contentType and dataType attributes fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Frondend

```
$.ajax({
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: '/GetList',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify({ 'Name': 'mehmet erdoğdu'}),
  beforeSend: function () {
  }, success: function (data) {
  }, complete: function () {
  }, error: function (data) {
  }
});
```

Backend

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetList([FromBody] NameRequest req)
{
    var selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = "",
            Text =  "Select Name"
        }
    };
    //
    return Json(selectListItems, new JsonSerializerSettings());
}
```